# What is wrong with this Switch statement? Im getting error cannot convert value text to type True/False

Tags: powerbi, dax

Season =
SWITCH(TRUE(),

'sales'[Month] = "December" || "January" , "Winter",

'sales'[Month] = "February" || "March" , "Spring",

'sales'[Month] = "April" || "May" || "June" , "Summer",

'sales'[Month] = "July" || "August" || "September" , "Monsoon",

'sales'[Month] = "October" || "November", "Autumn",

"NA")

Cannot convert value 'January' of type Text to type True/False.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to repeat the column reference in each statement. e.g.

```
sales'[Month] = "December" || sales'[Month] = "January" , "Winter",
```

Comment: Alternatively, do `IN {"December", "January"}`